# Is GAE memcache intended to work with django 1.4 correctly?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am working on a project written with use of `Django` framework and running on `GAE` instances. It also uses Google's `memcache` as a default cache backend. This project was developed with use of Django 1.3 and it works on it nicely. But recently we tried to run our project on Django 1.4 and run into a strange exception: `argument of type 'Client' is not iterable`.

The reason for this exception lies in [this](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c11f9c3193901215ec79732af6ab6c66b3c1c2ba#L0R31) commit. Here are two lines that have been added since Django 1.3:

```
    if (KEY_PREFIX + session_key) in cache:
        return True
```

These lines assume that `cache` object is iterable. Cache object itself is an instance of `google.appengine.api.memcache.Client` class as specified in project's `settings.py`. This  class indeed does not provide an iterable interface.

So my question: how is (if it is) `memcache` supposed to work with `Django 1.4`?

UPD. Here is a fragment from our `settings.py` related to the question:

```
    SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'google.appengine.api.memcache.Client',
         }
     }
```

Comment: Are you using django-nonrel?

Comment: No, it seems that we aren't.

Comment: Can you share how you configure your cache backend?

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo I added a fragment from our ``settings.py``. Is it what you were asking for?

Comment: I just encountered this problem today, did you find a solution?

Comment: @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin I didn't as far as I remember. We ended up using older version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I'm using django-nonrel, however I don't see any code that indicates this won't work on normal django (I could be wrong)

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    }
}
```